# Getting error "Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable." when using BigQuery client library in python?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, try-except

I am developing a GCP cloud function which will execute query on BigQuery table, load data into some temporary table and then that data may be used by some other cloud functions letter from this temporary table.

In my query I am using one table and I want to check that table's existence before i execute my query in cloud function. For that I have written two try except blocks, first one will check the table existence. If table is not already created then it will create that table with provided create_table query. After it should execute second try except block, but here I am getting error. first try except block is creating table if its not already created but after that it is getting failed to execute second try except block with error:

""***Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable.", _pickle.PicklingError: Pickling client objects is explicitly not supported. Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable.***"

As of now I have tried below code in python:

```
def main(request):
    my_client = bigquery.Client()
    create_table = 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE {}.{} (customerName STRING, IDNumber STRING)'.format(dest_dataset, dest_table)
    job_configs = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    destination_dataset = my_client.dataset(dest_dataset, dest_project)
    destination_table = destination_dataset.table(dest_table)
    job_configs.destination = destination_table

    # Check the final destination table is already exists, if not then create it based on create_table query.

    try:
        table = my_client.get_table(destination_table)
        if table:
            print('Table {}\'s existence sucessfully proved!'.format(destination_table))

    except NotFound as error:
        temporary_table = my_client.query(create_table, location='US')
        temporary_table.result()
        print('Table {} is created!'.format(destination_table))


    # After checking destination_table existance, run actual query (destination_table being used in this query) and load data into temporary table
    try:

        client = bigquery.Client()
        job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
        dest_dataset = client.dataset(temporary_dataset, temporary_project)
        dest_table = dest_dataset.table(temporary_table)
        job_config.destination = dest_table
        job_config.create_disposition = 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED'
        job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
        query_job = client.query(query, location='US', job_config=job_config)
        query_job.result()
        table = client.get_table(dest_table)
        expiration = (datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=expiration_time))
        table.expires = expiration
        table = client.update_table(table, ["expires"])
        logger.info("Query result loaded into temporary table: {}".format(temporary_table))

    except RuntimeError:
        logger.error("Exception occurred {}".format(RuntimeError))
```

Is there any way to resolve this error or any different approach to check the table existence

Comment: Can you share the entire stack trace?

Comment: @DustinIngram 
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 144, in __getstate__ "Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable.", _pickle.PicklingError: Pickling client objects is explicitly not supported. Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable.

Answer (score 1):

I got a workaround which resolved my problem, What I am trying to do is, I am writing 2 separate functions for each try except block as below:

```
def check_dest_table_existence(request):
    my_client = bigquery.Client()
    create_table = 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE {}.{} (customerName STRING, IDNumber STRING)'.format(dest_dataset, dest_table)
    job_configs = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    destination_dataset = my_client.dataset(dest_dataset, dest_project)
    destination_table = destination_dataset.table(dest_table)
    job_configs.destination = destination_table

    # Check the final destination table is already exists, if not then create it based on create_table query.

    try:
        table = my_client.get_table(destination_table)
        if table:
            print('Table {}\'s existence sucessfully proved!'.format(destination_table))

    except NotFound as error:
        temporary_table = my_client.query(create_table, location='US')
        temporary_table.result()
        print('Table {} is created!'.format(destination_table))



def main(request):

    # Check destination_table existance, run actual query (destination_table being used in this query) and load data into temporary table
    try:

        # Calling another function to check existence of destination table.
        check_dest_table_existence(request)

        client = bigquery.Client()
        job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
        dest_dataset = client.dataset(temporary_dataset, temporary_project)
        dest_table = dest_dataset.table(temporary_table)
        job_config.destination = dest_table
        job_config.create_disposition = 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED'
        job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
        query_job = client.query(query, location='US', job_config=job_config)
        query_job.result()
        table = client.get_table(dest_table)
        expiration = (datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=expiration_time))
        table.expires = expiration
        table = client.update_table(table, ["expires"])
        logger.info("Query result loaded into temporary table: {}".format(temporary_table))

    except RuntimeError:
        logger.error("Exception occurred {}".format(RuntimeError))
```